# Getting java.io.IoException while calling .net web service from my java code

Tags: android, ksoap

My Code:

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CallSoap {
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/SendMessage";

    public final String OPERATION_NAME = "SendMessage";

    public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://omega-solutions.in/ExpertsApp.asmx";

    public CallSoap() {
    }

    public String Call(String deviceid, String msg) {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
                OPERATION_NAME);
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("deviceid");
        pi.setValue(deviceid);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);
        pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("msg");
        pi.setValue(msg);
        pi.setType(String.class);
        request.addProperty(pi);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
        Object response = null;
        try {



            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);






            response = envelope.getResponse();
            Log.e("after", "" + "after");
        } catch (Exception exception) {

            Log.e("before", "" + "before" + exception.toString());
            response = exception.toString();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

When i run this code

```
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

I am getting `java.io.ioException` after above line of code.

Comment: post your logcat, need more info.

Comment: I am getting just  java.io.ioException nothing else

Comment: I'm not sure about the exception. And by the way you wil get many other exceptions like networkOnMainThread... you should use asynctask for network operation.I suggest you to change entire code.

Comment: Try this [link](http://andygeeks.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-get-data-from-soap-webservice.html) for ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the web method of your web service whether you have closed the connection or not.Because I have also faced the same problem but after closing the sql connection of my web method in my web service it has been resloved.... al the best.!!!!!